# Rake invoke breaks my each cycle

Tags: rake, rake-task, rakefile

I am trying to do an iteration with rake tasks, but when I use this example, the output show me always the first item inside my list. I want to reuse the task `:create`. Here is my code:

```
namespace :devops do
    desc "Task description"
    task :prepend do
        %W[config logs].each do | folder |
            task("devops:create").invoke("#{folder}")
        end    
    end

    desc "Create the folder structure"
    task :create, [ :name ] do |t, args| 
        puts "Creating the structure for <#{args[:name]}> folder"
    end
end
```

Here is the rake execution:

```
rake devops:prepend
```

Here is the output:

```
Creating the structure for <config> folder
```

It always takes the first argument, why? It is something like the task `invoke` breaks the each cycle? I don't know... any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I keep searching and I found that I miss a peace of code. To run a same task several time I need to do this:

```
task("devops:create").reenable
```

So the complete example will be:

```
namespace :devops do
    desc "Task description"
    task :prepend do
        %W[config logs].each do | folder |
            task("devops:create").invoke("#{folder}")
            task("devops:create").reenable
        end    
    end

    desc "Create the folder structure"
    task :create, [ :name ] do |t, args| 
        puts "Creating the structure for <#{args[:name]}> folder"
    end
end
```

And the result is:

```
Creating the structure for <config> folder
Creating the structure for <logs> folder
```